# Maven war plugin creates war with multiple versions of same jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I experience following problem. I've got a legacy application where the maven-war-plugin in following way:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</webappDirectory>
        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Particular situation was that there was a special folder WebRoot on level of src in the source tree of the project

[image]

Then when I had changed version of some dependency and started a build with
`mvn clean package` I got in the end a project.war with `WEB-INF/lib` which was filled with both versions of the artifact new and old one. That makes troubles during the start of the war in servlet container because it's not clear which of the jars gets loaded by classloader and there were different incompability problems with some jars.

EDIT:
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

```
[INFO] yyy:sometool:war:0.1.15-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-lgpl:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.opensymphony:xwork-core:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.4)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.8.2)
[INFO] |  |  \- (ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-convention-plugin:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-dojo-plugin:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- struts2plugin:struts2pluginLogin:jar:0.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-json-plugin:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-junit-plugin:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.8.1)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.5.ga)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.1.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.1.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- (javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.b2)
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- (c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.9.1.2)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.4)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.unto.twitter:java-twitter:jar:0.9-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.2)
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3)
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.4)
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.9.9)
[INFO] |  \- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] +- utils.networking:httpclient:jar:0.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- (junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.8.1)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.4)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |     +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.2.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.9.3)
[INFO] |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:compile
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to your question. It would help the troubleshooting process

Comment: Hardly ever you have multiple versions of the same artifact. I think you have different artifacts with the same "artifactId", but their "groupId" should be different. "dependency:tree" will help to find such cases.

Comment: @SergeBogatyrev It would be too easy, but added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was really this plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</webappDirectory>
    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
</configuration>
```

`webappDirectory` is by definition the place where maven put exploded war. So after `mvn clean package` there was a lib folder unter the `${basedir}/WebRoot` filled with all the dependency libs from the pom. On the other hand this folder is used for packaging into war. So each time I updated a version of some dependency and started `mvn clean package` a new version of the dependency got put into `${basedir}/WebRoot/lib` without removing the previous version. And after the next `mvn clean package` it got packaged the whole `lib` folder into the war.

The solution is, don't use the same folder for `warSourceDirectory` and `webappDirectory`. Point the `webappDirectory` somewhere into the `<webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/XYZ</webappDirectory>`